How can I access my host system's system (dbus) bus in a Distrobox container?
I'm using Distrobox to develop applications, and currently I'm working on one which interacts with a service running on the system bus.
To test for a connection to the system bus and the service I want to interact with, I use the following command:
$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1

This works if I run it on my host system, and gives me a list of interfaces along with their corresponding methods, signals, and properties. However, if I run it inside of my Distrobox container, it just gives me this:
$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1
Error connecting: Could not connect: No such file or directory

I presume this is due to that the Distrobox container doesn't have access to the host system's system bus, and I don't run any init system in the container itself. I want to allow applications running inside of this Distrobox container to be able to access my host system's system bus. How can I achieve this inside of a Distrobox container?

Bind mounting /run/dbus? No idea if that makes sense / is a good idea though?

In my case, setting the DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable to an appropriate value was a workable solution to this problem.
Setting this globally for the container can have some potentially unwanted consequences like "apt trying to fire up systemd inside the containers, if that path is found" (see discussion 1188 in the Distrobox repository for more information), so I just set it on a per-application basis as necessary by setting the environment variable like so in the command line:
DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

However, it is also possible to set it globally when creating a new container, like so:
distrobox create --additional-flags "--env DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"

In the aforementioned linked discussion, unix:///run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket was used instead of unix:path=/run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket. However, the former doesn't seem to be compatible with dbus-fast which is what I'm using for my application. It's possible some other implementations support the former format, but at least dbus-fast needs the latter one to work. It also doesn't work in the testcase I wrote in the original question:
$ DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:///run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1
Error connecting: Key/Value pair 0, “///run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket”, in address element “unix:///run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket” does not contain an equal sign

But the other format works:
$ DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/host/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1
node /org/freedesktop/login1 {
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer {
[details omitted for brevity]
  };
};

